# Data values not sending to the api. PHP + cURL

Tags: php, curl

```
$api = "xyz";
$data = array('emailId'=>'xyz@hotmail.com','name'=>'rohit','address' => 'noida',
        'city' => 'noida',
        'country' => 'india');
$data_json = json_encode($data);

$endpoint = "http://sdasfsafa/100/uszzzer/register";

$headers = array('api-key: '.$api , 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json));
$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POST => POST,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_json,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);
//print_r($headers);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch,$options); 
echo $response  = curl_exec($ch);


$decoderesponse = json_decode($response, true);


?>
<pre>
  <?php print_r($decoderesponse); ?>
</pre>
```

Please correct me where I am wrong, any help is appreciated. What I am currently doing is sending the data values to the api but api returns an error that the values send by me in body part is null.

```
Array ( [code] => -888 [status] => failed [message] => Kindly provide all the mandatory fields. (emailId, name, address, city, country) )
```

Comment: What is response and what is the error?

Comment: `Array ( [code] => -888 [status] => failed [message] => Kindly provide all the mandatory fields. (emailId, name, address, city, country) ) `

Comment: You need to find out if that API expects JSON or not and what format.  You are giving the fields but not in the format it expects.

Comment: and how i come to know about it ? like which api need what format

Comment: The API provider should provide docs or an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($result,true);
```

just add your reader and try it

in other case try 'postman' https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

it can export the Curl Code and you can implement to your file. i think it is helpfull . :)

Comment: Hi Tried your code and get the same error but i am trying the postman